# Node.js and ColdFusion on the same server?

Tags: node.js, coldfusion, application-server

I have question about how to set `Node.js` server application. On my server I have `ColdFusion` application server. I can test my code through browser `url`. I would like the same for `Node.js`. Node is already installed on my server but the only way to run the code is through `cmd` command window. First question is what I need in order for both to run on the same server? I still need my ColdFusion. Second question is about Nodes.js and can I set up server application with ISS or I need something else? Also do I have to specify what extension on my files will point to ColdFusion and other to Node. For example `.cfm` extension is for ColdFusion and `.js` is for the Node. If anyone knows anything about this or where I can find more information please let me know. I never experienced something similar and this is something completely new for me.

Comment: Maybe Ben Nadel has your answer? https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2173-using-socket-gateways-to-communicate-between-coldfusion-and-node-js.htm

Comment: @FrankTudor I found this link but that is just setting NodeJS: http://www.jhh.me/blog/2012/12/24/setting-up-http-server-on-windows-with-node-js/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I figure I'd provide an answer for those souls who are looking around.

If working with Apache 2.4.x.

In a test environment this would not be to much of an issue as Node and Coldfusion operate on different ports.

If your looking to create a production site than I would say that building a virtual host with proxy to the node site and Coldfusion would be another method.

If you are using the Coldfusion connector to Apache and loading node, than still loading the proxy for the node part would be fine, just make sure you are pointing to the correct port for your node.

Things to remember: 
You may have to alter internal Firewall rules. 
Comment your hosts files so you don't accidentally alter the wrong file.
Both can exist within the same platform.